# Table doesn't have a primary key when using object array

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

```
byte[] movieCover = null;
FileStream movieStream = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader movieReader = new BinaryReader(movieStream);
movieCover = movieReader.ReadBytes((int)movieStream.Length);
var movieTable = MovieTable();
var Starwars = new object[2];
Starwars[0] = "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace";
Starwars[1] = 1999; //Also tried using a string
var sw = movieTable.Rows.Find(Starwars);
```

sw is still null my table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movie] (
    [Name]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Release Year] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Producer]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Rating]       INT           NULL,
    [Covor]        IMAGE         NULL,
    [Description]  TEXT          NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Name] ASC, [Release Year] ASC)
);
```

I tried very hard to fix this myself but i've been stuck for days now! All i want to do is manually add a picture to it!

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved. To pull primary key follow [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310373)

You need to set DataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction to MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey before you call the Fill method.

```
DataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
```